# How to use a theme on the Android camera object?

Tags: android, camera, apk

I have a simple Android app with two screens. The first screen is the default camera. The second screen is for captured image review, and has a couple of buttons for taking action on the image.

I would like to use custom design (theme/skin) on the camera object in the first screen. How can I do that?

I have attached a mockup of both the screens. The first image is of camera preview and second is of image review. The end result that needs to be achieved with the camera preview, should be something like this:

[image: Camera Preview with theme]

Comment: can you show your code.? is your secound screen fragment/activity? have you tried to themed them?

Comment: Do you mean you have a full screen as the camera preview and you want to add a frame like a grid ?

Comment: Abhishek, unfortunately I can't share the code right now. I might be able to do so in a while. The second screen is not an activity. I do not need to theme it.

Comment: Xiaomi, you are right, I have the full screen as the camera preview and I need to replace the default shutter button, with a button which is captioned in my local language Hindi. I also want to add a couple of extra buttons to this preview screen.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add extra element like a button, you can just add them where

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dp">

        //Your camera preview
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_above="@+id/red_button" />

        //A Button on the camera preview near the bottom of the screen
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/take_picture"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/camera_preview"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:text="take picture" />

        <Button
            android:id="@id/red_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_margin="5dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

When the Frame layout add a surface view of your camera preview.

But I will not try to build into the surface view for a problem of performance, instead try to make your own custom view and override the onDraw method to directly draw on the view.

Comment: Thanks Xiaomi! Your advice seems helpful. I have added an image to the original question. Maybe it can help me explain myself better.